# Pig Tutorial: pig.jar location

Tags: java, mapreduce, installation, apache-pig

I am reading through and trying to complete this tutorial on Apache's website:

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/tutorial.html#Pig+Installation

I don't find any `pig.jar` in the pig-0.15.0 folder that I have unpacked. However, I do find `pig-0.15.0-core-h1.jar` and `pig-0.15.0-core-h2.jar`.

I wonder if this tutorial is outdated. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried just using one of the pig core jars that you unpacked instead of pig.jar? Better yet, you could rename one of them to `pig.jar` and try it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pig tutorial you are trying to use does not match the Pig release that you downloaded. You should refer to the tutorial in the Pig 0.15.0 documentation. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/start.html#tutorial